# Sketch $\dot x =x-y$, $\dot y= x+y$ on a phase portrait.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Sketch $$\begin{cases}\dot x =x-y
\newline\dot y= x+y\end{cases}$$ on a phase portrait.
The original question requires me to change the variables to polar ones, but then asks me to draw a phase portrait of the problem using the prior form and then the new form, and I am currently stuck with drawing it, for we were never guided to use multiplication of matrices and vectors, but to actually solve the equation, which I just can't. I tried dozen of things and it seems like I always get stuck with the endless integration. I could use some help here.

Comment: Begin by looking at the lines $x-y=0$ and $x+y=0$ where the vector field is vertical or horizontal. After  sketching it there, fill in the regions in between with transitions from vertical to horizontal.

Comment: Thank you, now it makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
Look at the picture and the system and notice that:

- In the Yellow Area: $y>x \Rightarrow \dot{x}<0 \;\;\;$ and $\;\;\; y<-x \Rightarrow \dot{y}<0$.
- In the Green Area: $\; y>x \Rightarrow \dot{x}<0 \;\;\;$ and $\;\;\; y>-x \Rightarrow \dot{y}>0$.
- In the Blue Area: $\;\;\; y<x \Rightarrow \dot{x}>0 \;\;\;$ and $\;\;\; y>-x \Rightarrow \dot{y}>0$.
- In the Red Area: $\;\;\;\; y<x \Rightarrow \dot{x}>0 \;\;\;$ and $\;\;\; y<-x \Rightarrow \dot{y}<0$.

Comment: So clear! Thank you!
I was afraid it is inadmissible.

Answer (score 5):

*One analytical way to find the diagram Did has in his answer:*

Writing $'$ for $d/dt$, then

$$xx' + yy' = x^2 + y^2$$

thus $\displaystyle \frac 12 (r^2)' = r^2$ and hence $r^2(t) = e^{2t}$ or $$r(t) = e^t$$

Meantime $\theta = \arctan(y/x)$ and

$$\theta' = \frac{1}{1 + y^2/x^2}\left( \frac{y'}{x} - \frac{y}{x^2}  x'\right) = \frac{xy' - yx'}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2 + y^2} = 1$$

Therefore the general solution is

$$\begin{align} x(t) & = c_1 e^t \cos t + c_2 e^t \sin t \\
                y(t) & = c_1 e^t \sin t - c_2 e^t \cos t
\end{align}$$

Angular velocity constant, $\theta' = 1$; radial distance growing exponentially, $r(t) = e^t$.

---

The more sophisticated method is to find the eigenvectors and general solution of the system

$$\frac{d\ }{dt} \left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array} \right)$$

The eigenvalues are $1 \pm i$, consistent with the general solution we have above.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Helped me a lot. I didn't understand, though, how you arrived at ${1\over 2}(r^2)'$.

Comment: As $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ and differentiating $(r^2)' = 2xx' + 2yy'$

Comment: Were is the general solution derived from? In the notes, many solutions were so far only "guessed" according to my teacher. I am completely lost.

Comment: If you haven't done it yet, you haven't done it yet and you probably will in the lectures to come. The diagram from Did is the best qualitative answer to date.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that there is only one equilibrium, $(0,0)$. If you find the Jacobian of this system, you will find that it is:$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right) $. You will find that the real part of the (complex) eigenvalues are positive, which implies that the origin is unstable. And since it is complex, it will be a spiral. Proceed similarly for the polar one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to write unstable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plot of the solutions, which `WA` calls `streamplot`. For an analytical solution explaining it, see [the answer posted by @SimonS](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1531020/6179).

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes on this answer